# Merge conflict error, when there was no change in mentioned file

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a site local repo and a remote repo.
Local repo contains the 1-2 month old content of remote repo.

I try to pull the whole content into local repo.

```
git pull origin master
From ssh://.../site.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
...
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in admin/process_email.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I checked process_email.php using P4Merge, but shows no conflict, furthermore there were no changes at all, no difference.

UPDATE:

I get

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean on both repos.
```

Also I tried

```
$ git pull -X theirs origin/master master
```

But still get the same error.

I want to merge the remote origin repo with my local repo.
I want to overwite local repo with remote origin repo content as the remote repo is newer, contains the latest code.

More than 2000 files are conflicting, while I checked the conflict and they have the same content. I would not want to do manual conflict handling.

I have 
autocrlf = False
in the .gitconfig.

Why do I get conflict error for files, which have exactly the same content?

Comment: Try open file in notepad or notepad++ and look to any tag that indicates merge failing, there's someone?

Comment: There are no any tags, yet.

Comment: That's extremely weird. If you get the error "CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in xxx", then there should be conflict markers in the file, and `git status` should report the file as a conflict (text: "both added").

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure you didn't run `git status` in the same repo and right after you got a conflict. But if you want to discard all your local changes, why are you running `git pull` which is meant to *merge* your changes with the remote?

Comment: I also have Git Extensions open, so I immediately see if there are changes which are not committed, yet. This is why I wrote, that more than 2000 files are conflicting. I use git pull, and I wrote after UPDATE: git pull -X theirs origin/master master

Comment: Yes git status shows files as a conflict (text: "both added"). BTW: Both repo has just one commit, the initial commit. This is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved the problem, based on solution used in following thread:

[How to handle/fix git add/add conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475387/how-to-handle-fix-git-add-add-conflicts/20626817#20626817)

```
# moved all files from the local workdir to another directory.
mv /workdir/* /old_content

# commit this change
git commit -m 'Resolve git Add/Add branch merge conflict by deleting conflicted folder and files in myconflictedfolder'

# do merge from remote
git pull origin master
```

Pull was executed successfully, no conflicts anymore.

I could now overwrite the old_content directory, if I want, then commit.

Best regards, 
Konrad

Comment: I've also had success moving the few necessary files to a new directory. Deleting the local brach, and recreating the branch.

Answer (score 2):

This can also occur if someone has forced push on the remote.
Quick fix is to reset hard on your local and then take pull

- `git reset --hard origin/master`
- `git pull`

Also one should avoid git force push.

Comment: An `add/add` conflict is not the results of a forced push, it is the result of adding the same file(s) in both branches. This solution will work anyway, though, when one is willing to discard the local branch.

Answer (score 0):

The messages says you have a `add/add` conflict, meaning that the file was added both in your branch and in the one you're merging. This limits Git's ability to merge because there's no common ancestor (i.e. you'll get conflicts for every part of the file different on both sides). Open the file in your text editor and see if you have conflict markers and resolve them.

Running `git status` will give you more information about what's goin on.

Once you're satisfied with the content of the file, run `git add` on it and `git commit`.

Comment: Updated original post.