# how can I change jekyll theme name when I searched my github blog?

Tags: ruby, github, themes, jekyll, blogs

I want to use the hydeout jekyll theme:

[image: jekyll theme name in the web page]

I am customizing my GitHub blog using a Jekyll theme.

There is a problem that my blog name is set to "hydeout jekyll theme."

I searched google but I have no idea how to change my blog name here.

Can you give any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ryankor.github.io/ still display the correct name, "Ryan's Tech", as defined in your [`_config.yml`](https://github.com/RyanKor/ryankor.github.io/blob/664a9c5ccd9c0ab073228a61b0d6dd28591e1c9f/_config.yml#L6).

Check "[Switch theme in an existing Jekyll installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905534/6309)": your `_config.yml` seems to be missing a `theme: jekyll-theme-hideout` line.

Comment: Oh, God! Finally! Thank you all!